# how to make tags?

Tags: database, django, forms, tags

if I have a question and answer system, and I want to add a tag feature, as for every question I should have some tags, separated by a comma (just like Stackoverflow):

1. I want to have a separate class model for that, with a foreign key to a question
2. In the form, I want the user to be able to add multiple tags, separated by a comma, and when the form is submitted, I want the tags to be stored in a table: each tag a registration

What should I use in the form, so that the tags separated by a comma to be saved in the database, each tag a registration? (for easy searching)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree that you'd better use reusable tagging app, but if you're not afraid to get your hands dirty, check out [Django contenttypes framework](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/)

Answer (score 7):

[django-taggit](http://github.com/alex/django-taggit)

update: read the docs to see how the tag input string results in tags, http://github.com/alex/django-taggit/blob/master/docs/forms.txt

Comment: hmmm... i'm afaraid to use it, i'm a beginner and afraid not to be able to understand the code in a short time

Comment: Seems like a good replacement for non-maintained django-tagging.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah.. contenttypes framework is the best way to create tags.

```
class TagName(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        pass


class Tag(Model):
    tag = models.ForeignKey(TagName, related_name="tag_objects")
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, blank=True, null=True)
    object_id = models.TextField(ugettext('object id'), blank=True, null=True)
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    class Meta:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

as per 2020, this is working, simple django solution: 
models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class ExamplePost(models.Model):
    Title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Tags = models.ManyToManyField('Need', related_name='plants')
    entry_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.species}'

class ExampleTag(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Link = models.URLField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True, default="None")
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.title}'
```

In example.html:

```
  <div class="card-body">
      <h2 class="card-title">{{ ExamplePost.title }}</h2>
      <h5> Tags : </h5>
          <ul class="list-group list-group-horizontal-sm">
              {% for Tag in ExamplePost.tags.all %}
              <p class="p-2 bg-light text-warning">
                  <h3><span class="badge badge-pill badge-warning">{{ ExampleTag.name }} </span></h3>
                  </p>
              {% endfor %}
          </ul>
  </div>
```